# QGIS sorting as 1, 10, 100 not 1, 2, 3

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, sorting

I suspect I'm missing something basic but when ever I sort a table with an integer field it ends up sorting 1, 10, 100, not 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Are you sure that the field is not a text field.  If it is a text field they will sort like that 1,10,100,2,20,200, etc... Have you tried creating a int field and calculating them to int?  I know you said it was an int field but sometimes qgis can be strange when importing things.

Comment: Just to double check, I created a new scratch layer, and used QGIS to create 3 fields, whole, real, and int4.  Into each I created new points, and added the following data into each column: 1,3,10,100,2.  I then viewed the attribute table, and clicked on each column to "sort" them in ascending order.  Each column's sorted value ended up being '1, 10, 100, 2, 3'

Comment: What version of qgis you are you testing this on? There was a bug that got fixed in 2.16.1, see http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15295

Comment: @SaultDon - I am running 2.16.  I tested it on a different machine running 2.14 and couldn't reproduce the issue.  Upgraded the misbehaving machine to 2.18 fixed the issue.  If you repost as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bug related to http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15295 and was hopefully fixed for versions >= 2.16. It caused number fields to be sorted like text.

Upgrading to at least 2.18 should resolve it!

Comment: Just went back and tested, seems like it was only broken in 2.16.  Upgrading to 2.18 solved the issue.